# getParcelableExtra returns null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

After passing a Full-sized photo from the camera activity to another activity, when I tried to use getParcelableExtra on destination activity, it returns null. I think Destination activity starts before data gets passed. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code.  The code should include the photo object, where you sent it from and where you received it. If you are passing a value through an intent it will be available at `OnCreate` possibly even before. So that is probably not your issue.

Comment: Now, I have passed Uri instead of Bitmap. BTW thanks @avalerio

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek Ashware getParcelableExtra is not meant for passing huge data as image. Overall there is a restriction on the size of data that can be passed between activities, that is basically bundle size limit.

Best way is to pass the uri(path) of the image that will be a string from Camera activity to Another Activity. In the receiver activity, that uri can be used to retrieve the image.